# No module named lxml from python using php

Tags: php, python, python-2.7, lxml, elementtree

I'm having a problem in using python's plugin **lxml**. When I execute `python python.py` it works in the server but when I use php `system("python python.py")` it goes blank.

Python code:

```
from lxml import etree

# create XML 
root = etree.Element('root')
root.append(etree.Element('child'))
# another child with text
child = etree.Element('child')
child.text = 'some text'
root.append(child)

# pretty string
s = etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True)
print s
```

I used the `tail -f /var/log/httpd/error_log` to know what's happening to my php.

I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "xml.py", line 1, in ?
from lxml import etree
ImportError: No module named lxml
```

Comment: Maybe, you need to write the full path to python script?

Comment: @user4035 . the python.py is right beside my sample.php.

Comment: Probably the user PHP is running as has a different python path then your shell user. If the web server user has access to the directory where that module is located, you can add it to the python path. Or, you can install the module locally and make sure it can be imported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running following command on the terminal:

```
> whereis python
```

This will tell you where your python is installed. For example it could be /usr/local/bin for example. Once you get the correct path you can refer complete path in the system command.

If the above doesn't work, try doing this on terminal

```
python
>>> import lxml
>>> print lxml
<module 'lxml' from '<your_path>/site-packages/lxml-3.2.3-py2.7.egg/lxml/__init__.pyc'>
```

You should get a response similar to above. This will tell you from where you lxml package is being loaded. Based on this path you can check what may be going wrong in loading this package.

If the above option doesn't work, you can uninstall the lxml package and then reinstall it with following option:

```
easy_install -Z lxml
```

This will give you the source code of lxml package. And you can copy its code your source directory, and work further. But I would suggest this to be the last resort to try.

Comment: i have two pythons 2.7 and 2.4

Comment: my lxml is loaded in python2.7

Comment: Since lxml is installed for python2.7, can you check if php code is also loading it from python2.7?

Comment: no. it can't run. but i tried on php system("python python.py"). it worked. by the way. thanks :D

Answer (score 2):

Where is the `lxml` package installed?

The error suggests it is not on the PYTHONPATH when the python command is executed.  You need to ensure `lxml` is on the PYTHONPATH. This is most likely the case if installed in a non-standard location.

If `lxml` is installed in `site-packages` for Python 2.7 perhaps a mixture of python versions are being used.  It might be worth qualifying the version of python you expect to use (and have `lxml` installed for):

```
system("python2.7 python.py")
```

Comment: **This is most likely the case if installed in a non-standard location.** maybe this is my fault. i installed the package on a different location and executed python setup.py install. 

my python version is 2.7.2

Comment: So you may need to tell Python (when run from PHP) where lxml is by either setting the PYTHONPATH environment variable, or modifying sys.path in your python.py script. Might be worth confirming you are executing python 2.7 too - just calling the 'python' executable will give you the default version.